# RxJava-Aynchronous Stream Processing

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java

I am implementing a simple data analytic functionality with RXJava, where a topic subscriber asynchronously processes the data published to a topic, depositing the output to the Redis.

When a message is received, the Spring component publishes it to an Observable. To avoid blocking the submission I used the RxJava Async to do this asynchronously.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(final TransactionalMessage message) {
    Async.start(new Func0<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            analyser.process(message);
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

I have two confusions in implementing other processing parts; 1) creating an asynchronous Observable with buffering 2) Computing different logics **in parallel** based on message type on list of messages.

After long experiments I found two ways to create the Async Observable and not sure which one is the right and better approach.

Way one,

```
private static final class Analyzer {

private Subscriber<? super TransactionalMessage> subscriber;

public Analyzer() {
    OnSubscribe<TransactionalMessage> f = subscriber -> this.subscriber = subscriber;
    Observable.create(f).observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5, Schedulers.io())
            .skipWhile((list) -> list == null || list.isEmpty())
            .subscribe(t -> compute(t));
}
public void process(TransactionalMessage message) {
        subscriber.onNext(message);
    }
```

}

Way two

```
private static final class Analyser {

private PublishSubject<TransactionalMessage> subject;

public Analyser() {
    subject = PublishSubject.create();
    Observable<List<TransactionalMessage>> observable = subject
            .buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5, Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation());
    observable.subscribe(new Observer<List<TransactionalMessage>>() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        log.debug("[Analyser] onCompleted(), completed!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        log.error("[Analyser] onError(), exception, ", e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<TransactionalMessage> t) {
        compute(t);
    }
    });
}

public void process(TransactionalMessage message) {
    subject.onNext(message);
}
}
```

The TransactionalMessage comes in different types, so I want to perform different computations based on the types. One approach I tried is filter the list based on every type and process them separately, but this looks so bad and I think does not work in parallel. What way to process them in parallel?

```
protected void compute(List<TransactionalMessage> messages) {
        Observable<TransactionalMessage> observable = Observable
                .from(messages);
        Observable<String> observable2 = observable
                .filter(new Func1<TransactionalMessage, Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(TransactionalMessage t) {
                        return t.getMsgType()
                                .equals(OttMessageType.click.name());
                    }
                }).flatMap(
                        new Func1<TransactionalMessage, Observable<String>>() {

                            @Override
                            public Observable<String> call(
                                    TransactionalMessage t) {
                                return Observable.just(
                                        t.getMsgType() + t.getAppId());
                            }
                        });

        Observable<String> observable3 = observable
                .filter(new Func1<TransactionalMessage, Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(TransactionalMessage t) {
                        return t.getMsgType()
                                .equals(OttMessageType.image.name());
                    }
                }).flatMap(
                        new Func1<TransactionalMessage, Observable<String>>() {

                            @Override
                            public Observable<String> call(
                                    TransactionalMessage t) {
                                return Observable.just(
                                        t.getMsgType() + t.getAppId());
                            }
                        });

        // I sense some code smell in filtering on type and processing it.

        Observable.merge(observable2, observable3)
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(String t) {
                        // save it to redis
                        System.out.println(t);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest thinking about `Subject`s before attempting to use `create`.

If you want parallel processing done based on some categorization, you could use `groupBy` along with `observeOn` to achieve the desired effect:

```
Observable.range(1, 100)
.groupBy(v -> v % 3)
.flatMap(g -> 
     g.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
     .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
     .map(v -> g.getKey() + ": " + v)
)
.toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```